# apache-camel : How to split a collections of objects and iterate on each on them?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I work with apache camel. In my route,i receive a list of Object Person :

```
 from("direct:handle")  
     .bean(PersonneProcessor.class)      // The new exchange contains the list of Person List<Person>
     1 =>????                            // Here i want to split My list to have one Person 
    .bean(HandelOneProcessor.class)    // Here i want to process One Person by One. Here i could simple bean or Processor. Possiilities are many.
```

1=> I saw some example on internet which split just String and not Object.
How to split a collections of objects and iterate on each on them ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [split EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html) as follow:

```java
 from("direct:handle")  
   .bean(PersonneProcessor.class)
   .split(body())
   .bean(HandelOneProcessor.class)
```